# die function produces syntax error when used with use function

Tags: perl, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a backup system in Perl.  Eventually, I want to share it with the world.  But I want to make sure that people have the correct modules installed, so I want to have some exception handling in case they don't have the correct modules.  Ironically, the die function produces a syntax error when I use it in the following situation:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Tk or die "You don't have the Tk module installed."
```

How can I adjust this to get the desired effect?

Comment: This seems like something you should handle at install instead of trying to enforce in the application-level.

Comment: `use Tk` is not a valid expression. You can't do `use Tk or ...;` or `( use Tk ) + 4`  any more than you can do `while (1) { } or ...;` or `( while(1) { } ) + 4`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [use](https://perldoc.pl/functions/use) statement is special, it does not work like a function call. It executes at compile time unlike most statements, and parses the remainder of the statement with a unique syntax - namely that the module name must be a bareword, and following that can be an optional module version followed by the list of arguments.

Just `use Tk;` will already throw an exception if Tk is not found, you don't need to do any checking of your own. If you want to customize the error message, you can load it in a runtime statement with [require](https://perldoc.pl/functions/require) and trap the exception, but you should really include the contents of `@INC` or the original error message which contains that, for debugging where the module should be found:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
  unless (eval { require Tk; Tk->import; 1 }) {
    die "You don't have the Tk module installed: $@";
  }
}
```

Dependencies for a CPAN distribution are specified in metadata and by the configure script for the distribution, this ensures they are installed when the user tries to install your distribution with a CPAN client. See http://blogs.perl.org/users/neilb/2017/05/specifying-dependencies-for-your-cpan-distribution.html. For code distributed outside of CPAN, a [cpanfile](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanfile) provides a format for specifying dependencies that can easily be installed by the user with [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm).

Comment: Note that your alternate doesn't import like the original. The equivalent would actually be: `BEGIN { unless (eval("use Tk; 1")) { ... } }`

Comment: You might need to `Tk->import()` to emulate `use` behavior. https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/use.html

Comment: Updated. String eval is not needed here, but the import does often need to happen at compile time, like in a BEGIN.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `unless`? Why can't you just `BEGIN { eval { require Tk; Tk->import }; die "..." if $@ }`? (these are not rhetorical questions; I'm genuinely curious why you did that).

Comment: @mosvy https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny#BACKGROUND explains several reasons why relying on the value of `$@` to detection an exception state should be avoided. The return value of `eval` is reliable: when an exception has occurred, it returns undefined (in scalar context), so as long as it returns a true value at the end, it can reliably make the distinction.

Comment: `eval { ...; 1 } or die $@` is another way you could construct this particular idiom.